# Obter totais por intervalo de datas, relacionando com tabela adicional

Tags: mysql

O caso é o seguinte, tenho uma tabela no MySQL referente ao caixa de uma empresa, e estou criando uma tabela no JAVA que vai ser um centro de custos.
A tabela do banco de dados tem as colunas:

```
id | data | descricao | id_tipoDespesa | valor |
```

eu preciso do valor total de cada despesa em um intervalo especifico de datas e também relacionar o `id_tipoDespesa` com o tipo de despesa que ele representa.

o resultado que eu preciso é como no exemplo:

```
periodo:
de: data1 até: data2

despesa  | valor |
__________________
agua     | 1000  |
luz      | 2004  |
telefone | 503   |
```

eu ainda não sei quase nada sobre MySQL e nenhuma outra linguagem de banco de dados, por favor tentem explicar o mais simples possível kkkk

Comment: Quando você diz "[...]estou criando uma tabela no JAVA[...]" é uma espécie de `gridview` só pra exibir os dados? Ou armazenar algo também?

Comment: Aqui tem alguns exemplos de JOIN: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/70 O join serve para relacionar tabelas por determinadas condições e/ou colunas. Mas se você ainda não sabe muito de BD, sugeriria começar com coisa mais simples, e ir fazendo perguntas específicas sobre cada passo que tiver dificuldade. O Stack Overflow em Português é um site de Perguntas e Respostas, e não um fórum com tutoriais. Tem umas dicas que podem te ajudar a aproveitar melhor o site em [Tour], [Tópicos adequados ao site](/help/on-topic), [Ask]. Resolvendo as dúvidas passo a passo é o melhor caminho.

Comment: Um jeito simples de testar SQL e Joins é ler o link indicado acima, e aplicar no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com), assim dá para você compartilhar seus testes e a comunidade ajudar. Criando um [mcve] com dados de exemplo, no formato que deseja os resultados facilita para todos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você tem vários problemas numa questão só.

### Agrupamento e soma

Um deles é o problema do agrupamento e totalização. Você tem vários lançamentos para `id_tipos` diferentes, mas quer mostrar um por linha com seus totais.

A solução para isso é agrupar com `GROUP BY`, e obter o valor com `SUM`:

```
SELECT   SUM(valor)
FROM     despesas
GROUP BY id_tipos;
```

### Selecionando intervalo de datas

Como você quer um intervalo específico, precisamos limitar a *query* acima com uma condição (`WHERE`). Poderíamos dizer `WHERE data >= data_inicial AND data <= data_final`, mas para facilitar, há um operador para isso, o `BETWEEN`:

```
SELECT   SUM(valor)
FROM     despesas
WHERE    `data` BETWEEN "2016-04-01" AND "2016-07-30"
GROUP BY id_tipos
;
```

### Relacionando com a outra tabela

A *query* acima já dá os totais, mas faltou o tipo da despesa em questão. Para isso, usamos o `JOIN`, condicionado com `ON`:

```
SELECT    tipo,
          SUM(valor) AS total
FROM      despesas
LEFT JOIN tipos ON tipos.id = id_tipos
WHERE     `data` BETWEEN "2016-04-01" AND "2016-07-30"
GROUP BY  id_tipos
;
```

Veja funcionando e faça mais testes no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/622a7d/1)**;

#### Considerações gerais

- **Importante**: O correto para campos com **data e hora** é a o formato a seguir:

  ```
    WHERE `data` BETWEEN "2016-04-01 00:00:00" AND "2016-07-30 23:59:59"
  ```

  notar o `23:59:59` no horário da data final, que é para pegar eventos ocorridos durante o dia todo. Se omitir a hora, os resultados.
- O `GROUP BY` separa os resultados do `SUM` (ou quaisquer outras funções de agrupamento) em linhas separadas de acordo com os campos selecionados
- O `AS total` no `SUM` serve para dar um apelido amistoso para a coluna, que retornará com o nome de `total`, para facilitar o uso na aplicação
- Usamos prefixo em `tipos.id` no `ON` para desambiguação, pois o campo `id` existe nas duas tabelas. Estamos deixando claro que se trata do `id` da tabela `tipos`

Aprenda mais sobre `JOIN` em

> [Qual é a diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/70)

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado. foi uma ótima explicação, a única dúvida que restou foi quanto a parte : "SELECT tipo,"   esse tipo é a tabela tipo ou a coluna tipo?

Comment: A sintaxe é sempre SELECT [colunas ou dados] FROM [tabela] JOIN [tabela] ON tabela.coluna = tabela.coluna . Pode ser também SELECT tabela.coluna, mas quando tem um nome só, sem ponto, é sempre coluna ou valor.

Comment: Editei o post para desambiguar A hora que o SQL Fiddle resolver voltar a funcionar, atualizo lá também..